# Am I getting the stimulus check?

Tags: covid-19, stimulus

I am 20 years old and live with my mom, last year (2018) she filed me as a dependent, and I only just did my taxes on the 14th of April. I’m terrified I won’t be qualified in time. Does anyone know if I’ll get the check? Do they only look at your information one time?

Comment: Can she claim you for 2019? (i.e., does she pay for more than 50% of your living expenses)

Comment: She did not claim me for 2019. I’m just afraid they already looked at my information before my 2019 taxes went through and now they won’t send the check. (If they only saw my 2018 information, I wouldn’t get one)

Comment: Did you get a refund when you filed for 2019? Did you put direct deposit information or will a check be mailed to you? The IRS started sending out the stimulus via direct deposits on 4/15, and paper checks will be sent later.